# Java reflection for nested object

Tags: java, reflection

I need to write some code for providing default values for nested objects. I have 4 layers of object and those nested objects can have primitive as well collections (list/map) and I need to provide default values for all of them. How should I go about that? I was looking Java reflection but didn't get much example or way to do for nested objects?

Comment: Four levels of object nesting? I think your code may need refactoring. Regardless, can you provide an example of what the objects look like and what kind of default values you would like to provide for them and in which situations?

Comment: Is reflection a requirement? You could use a factory to create a Visitor for the specific class which would set the default values.

Comment: I am already using visitor to visit all the fields.

Comment: This is my structure:class TopOne{

private Nested1 nested1;
private string name;

TopOne.set(nested1);
}

class Nested1{

private Nested2 nested2;
private string value;

Nested1.set(nested2);
}

class Nested2{

private List<String> list;
}

Comment: Is the nested structure fixed or can be dynamic? Do you know those structures before hand? And are the default values fixed or dynamic as well?

Comment: it can be dynamic. so planning to have generic one.